# Cakephp join condition error

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, conditional-statements

I have two tables `employees` and `posting`.

`employees` with fields `id`,`name`

AND

`postings` with fields `id`,`employee_id`,`status`

Now to retrieve all the employees(with posting details) whose `Posting.status = 1`, I wrote in `PostingsController.php`'s `view()` action:

```
$cond = array('Posting.status'=>1);
$e = $this->Employee->find('all',array('conditions' => $cond));
$this->set('emp',$e);
```

In `Employee.php` model `var $hasMany = 'Posting';`

In `Posting.php` model `var $belongsTo = 'Employee';`

But the above code generates an error like :

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Posting.status' in 'where clause'

Generated SQL:

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`name` FROM `cakelab`.`employees` AS `Employee` WHERE `Posting`.`status` = 1
```

I am new to CakePhp joins, please guide me.

Comment: please post the generated SQL query that gives you that error

Comment: Two possible reasons (that i can think of):

 1. You have some typing error in the models (in the `hasMany` or the `belongsTo`).
 2. Your `recursive` option is set to -1, somewhere.

Please copy paste the relevant parts of the models.

also, you mentioned that you are new to cake's join, it is transparent to the user if not used specifically - have you tapered with it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake doesn't join the tables when the relation type is hasMany. Rather it performs a query on the first table (`employees`) and with the `id` of the employee it performs a second query on `postings` table to retrieve all the postings related to that employee

you can manually join the tables but I suggest querying on postings table and then group by Employee

```
$this->Posting ->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array('Employee.id', 'Employee.name', 'Posting.status' ),
        'conditions' => $cond,
        'group' => array('Employee.id')
    )
);
```

Comment: Thyanks arilia for nice explanation . Working nicely